# Batch File Loop Back to Start

Tags: batch-file

I have scoured the site and have been able to extract code which virtually handles all that I am seeking to achieve.  However, I cannot get the last bit to work which is to loop back to the start if I want to re-key another Sheet Number.  The code I have:

```
@Echo Off

cd "C:\temp\CopiedTo"

del *.* /Q

CLS
:start

@Echo Off
Set /P SheetNo=Enter the Sheet Number to Copy:

if exist "C:\temp\%SheetNo%.txt" (Copy "c:\temp\%sheetNo%.txt" "c:\temp\copiedto"

) Else (Echo set choice=
set /p choice="This Sheet Number Is Currently Not in the Directory - Do you wish to Re-Key Again? Press 'y' and enter for Yes: "
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='y' goto start
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `%choice%` variable inside a block. So you need delayed expansion.
Put a

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the beginning of your script and use `!choice!` instead of `%choice%` inside the block.

And: remove the `echo`  before `set choice=` (probably there for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, with a simpler interface.

Note that an automated `del *.*` on it's own is a dangerous command when the preceding `cd` command can fail and whatever directory is current can be nuked, so it's always best to specify the folder or do some extra testing to check if the CD failed.

The `CD` command now has the `/d` switch to cater for another drive being current.

```
@Echo Off
cd /d "C:\temp\CopiedTo"
del "C:\temp\CopiedTo\*.*" /Q

CLS
:start

@Echo Off
set "sheetno="
Set /P "SheetNo=Enter the Sheet Number to Copy (press enter to quit): "

if not defined sheetno goto :EOF

if exist "C:\temp\%SheetNo%.txt" (
        echo copying "%sheetNo%.txt"
        Copy "c:\temp\%sheetNo%.txt" "c:\temp copiedto" >nul
    ) Else (
        echo "Sheet Number "%sheetNo%.txt" Is Currently Not in the Directory
    )
goto :start
```